# Grace period edit revision

Tags: feature-request, edits, grace-period

I answered a question and same time some other person answered same question. That answer was wrong and I down-voted it.

Then I saw the other person edit his answer and OP has accepted his answer.

This person has put a comment saying;

> it's a correct answer I don't know why someone downvoted

I cannot see the revision of his answer may be because of the [grace-period](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/grace-period/info).

Is there any feature that allow me to see the revision within grace-period to prove that I down-voted the wrong answer, not the correct one?

As per my knowledge, if the votes are equal, old answers are displaying at the top. Most of the times question asker accept the first correct answer at the top if the quality of the answer looks similar. Some people misuse this grace-period feature to pretend that they posted the correct answer first, by posting incorrect or incomplete answers and editing them within grace-period.

My suggestion is to keep the first revision as it is and keep other edits within 5 minuets as second revision to overcome this misuse to some extend.

Comment: If the answer got edited, and now correctly answers the question, remove the downvote.

Comment: Yes, I can remove it, but it is better I can prove it was wrong since he has put the comment.

Comment: Better for whom? If the answer *is* correct now, the downvote is pointless.

Comment: Sure, I'll remove the down-vote. Other person is saying that he didn't edit it. That's why I want to see the revision.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138017/make-first-draft-of-a-new-answer-part-of-the-permanent-revision-history

Comment: "to **pretend** that they posted the correct answer" !! That's a huge allegation to make without any data.

Comment: "pretend that they posted the correct answer **first**" If we have the first revision, we have the data.

Comment: This isn't a fight or a competition. It's a **collective** effort to build a knowledge base. It's meant for years to come. Five minutes doesn't play any role in that, team spirit does.

Comment: Yes, I understand that part. Good attitudes and discipline should be there with team spirit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently the very first version of the question/answer *is* stored in the database but it's not shown if there are edits within the 5 minute grace period, so there's no way to prove things like this unless you get someone with database access involved. There's very little chance that the community managers would respond to such a request unless there was something very seriously wrong with the post.

If the answer is now correct then remove your down-vote. If you can't because it's locked then either make an edit yourself or ask the OP to edit the answer so you can revoke the vote.

Comment: Is there any onus to remove the downvote? AFAICT there's not. As far as I remember, Robert Harvey prominently stated in one of the few FGITW meta-posts, that he **will** vote on the post when he sees it as he sees it, and **won't** go change his vote because OP added the answer / corrected later (e.g. in the grace-period).

Comment: @Deduplicator - There is no onus to remove the down-vote.