# Editing a revision within the grace period of the revision should update the revision description for the edit if changed

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, edits, revision-history

[Here is an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69773144/584676) I just ran into this with, thought I could squeeze an edit or two in before the 5 minute marker but failed to do. I attempted to modify the revision message to be more clear as to what I changed but while the post content (I changed a couple of additional things as well) made it into the second revision, my updated revision message did not. This is something I've run into other times as well but figured I have some time to suggest this as a [feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) this time.

Note that this behavior persists on subsequent revisions, not just on the first one. It seems that this behavior is [by design](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271385/changing-edit-summary-of-a-previous-revision), however, I propose allowing edits within the grace period of a revision to update the revision message as part of the edit if it changes.

Note that this [is similar to another](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267885/grace-period-edit-revision) [feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) although distinct as that request asks that grace-period edits from the *first* be counted as a *second* revision (essentially nullifying the grace-period). I am proposing that modified edit reasons within *any* revision's grace-period be honored and updated, I am not proposing a "second" revision for this at all.

Comment: Yes, this is a gross violation of the [principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment), but it will never be fixed. We have to live with it (as we have for the past 13 years). A workaround is to let your automation (for example, macro keys) insert extra lines at the end.

Comment: @PeterMortensen What do you mean by "insert extra lines at the end" as a workaround?

Comment: Also, is there a known reason why this can't/won't be fixed? Or has this been asked in the past and fallen on deaf ears?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I hate to surprise you, but it [seems to have been fixed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/415772/584676), or at least implemented on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems this has been implemented, at least on Stack Overflow. Here is an edit [I recently made](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/70957486/2) (revision 2) consisting of two separate edits. The first did not have an edit message, and originally contained "modified X characters" message. The second edit I included a real message, along with another modification to the post, and the new message is shown in the revision history.